# CheckBox in ListView populated by Adapter

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I've done reading regarding this problem but seems like I can't figure it out.

I tried setting on the checkboxes focusable and focusable on touch to false, in the root layout block descendents but still nothing. I don't manage to fire up the event for clicking on the checkbox.

Here's the event:

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                if (checkBox.isChecked())
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The layout I inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ECF0F1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_picture"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sm_profile"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_picture"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Party"
                android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter class:

```
public class FilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilters;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mPictures;
    private Typeface Bebas, DroidSans;


    public FilterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filters, ArrayList<Integer> pictures) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFilters = filters;
        this.mPictures = pictures;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFilters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
        }

        DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

        ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
        TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes);

        filter_category.setTypeface(DroidSans);
        filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
        filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
```

Main XML for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.enloop.Fragments.DrawerFragments.Filter.CheckinFilters">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/select_category_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/action_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_btn_from_maps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ab_icon_menu"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/enloop_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_btn_from_maps"
                android:background="@drawable/ab_logo"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/center_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_layout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_layout">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/filter_categories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:queryHint="Search"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/check_in_lay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/check_in_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ab_icon_checkins"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/check_in_image"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/check_in_image"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/notifications_status"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
                    android:textSize="6dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/message_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/check_in_lay">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/message_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ab_icon_message"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/message_image"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/message_image"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/notifications_status"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
                    android:textSize="6dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/notification_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_layout">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/notification_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ab_icon_notification"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/notification_image"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notification_image"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/notifications_status"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="17"
                    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
                    android:textSize="6dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_category_action_bar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filters_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="CHECK-IN FILTERS"
            android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filter_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_layout"
        android:background="#ECF0F1"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Setting Adapter to ListView:

```
mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_list);
        filterAdapter = new FilterAdapter(view.getContext(), l, drawables);
        mListView.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
```

Comment: Show your adapter class.

Comment: The above posted xml file is category_filter_item???

Comment: Yes, now I put the XML for the fragment as well.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `onClickListener` on the checkbox itself in your adapter's `getView` method like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if (checkBox.isChecked())
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Edit:

your `getView` method should be like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
    }

    DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

    ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
    TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    checkBox .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if (checkBox.isChecked())
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    filter_category.setTypeface(DroidSans);
    filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
    filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: make sure you inflated the view first with your row XML layout

Comment: I'm setting the adapter on the listview before doing this, so the checkboxes should be in there already

Comment: please post the code where you initialize the adapter and set it to the list view.

Comment: check my updated answer, and like Piyush Gupta said, your checkbox id is wrong.

Comment: It was an error while editing my answer, it's fixed but it's still not working. Although, if I set the event in the Adapter class, it's working. Was wondering why not the other way around.

Also, would it still be possible to save the state of the checked boxes from the Adapter class? Since that's what I wanted to achieve in the first place

Comment: you should set the event in the adapter class in order for it to work, please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you but this is not the solution I'm looking for. I want to set the event in the main class, since Checkbox is part of the row that I inflate using the adapter --> Therefore onItemListChecked should be the option for me. Problem is how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement onCheckChange Listener instead Item Click Listener :

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }
});
```

Formmated Adapter code with [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern :

```
public class FilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilters;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mPictures;


    public FilterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filters, ArrayList<Integer> pictures) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFilters = filters;
        this.mPictures = pictures;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFilters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
            holder.filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
            holder.filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            holder.filter_category.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf"));
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
        holder.filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item at " + position + " is Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView filter_img;
        TextView filter_category;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you remove listviw item click listener ?

Comment: Thank you but this is not the fix I want. I want to be able to use OnItemClick Listener since the CheckBox is part of the row I inflate

Comment: Exactly where I set the event since the instance of Checkbox is null.

Comment: Yes, this will work if I set the event in the Adapter. I want to be able to use OnItemClickListener in the main Fragment, not in the adapter

Comment: No item click never called so you have to implement in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `inflated` view has a id for `Checkbox` is `checkbox` while you are using in `getView()` method

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes);// this is wrong.
```

So you need to change via

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
```

in `getView()` method or just in your `category_filter_item.xml` file change ID for `Checkbox` to `checkboxes`.

Comment: Good observation, but it was a change I made while editing my answer. Everything is set up properly now and still getting the error.

Comment: After I use the findViewByID. It works if I set the event in the Adapter class, was wondering why not the other way around?

Comment: Because it was inflated in getView() method in adapter class and ID was wrong. I think there is no any big issue..

Comment: ID is not a problem, like I said, it was a small error while editing my answer. The ID is alright now, still throwing me error if I try to set the event in Filter class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64864/discussion-between-pop-alex-cristian-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

This is not in the Adapter class. See ID in here.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

ID in filter class:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
        }

        DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

        ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
        TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
```

And the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.enloop.Fragments.DrawerFragments.Filter.CheckinFilters.onCreateView(CheckinFilters.java:104)
```

Which is exactly where I'm setting the event.